# How can I redial using Voice Control or Siri?

Tags: iphone, siri, voice-dictation

Is it possible to dial the last dialed phone number on iOS via Voice Control or Siri?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We can't answer for Apple's decisions here. I've edited your question to focus on what you want to accomplish. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but not yet.  Apple could add this in the future, but it isn't in iOS under Voice Control or Siri currently.  If you know who called, you could ask for them by name.  Unfortunately, that's the only solution with Siri.

Answer (score 1):

I was driving down the freeway yesterday and my phone call was cut off. Sounds like the perfect time to tell Siri to redial. I was shocked that Siri does not do this after being in release for so long.

Comment: How is this different from the other answer here?

Answer (score 1):

The current iOS version 9 allows Siri to dial the last number. Just say “Redial that last number”.